# Repeatedly iterating over an Iterator

Tags: scala, loops, iterator, traversal, repeat

For a game I need to repeatedly iterate over the players of the game. I guess in Scala the Iterator seams to be the best option for that use case, since with an iterator `it` you can call `it.next()` whenever you need the next element and don't run through all of them at the same time.

Iterators have a `it.hasDefiniteSize` and a `it.isTraversableAgain` operation which suggest that infinite or repeated iterations somehow exists. But I couldn't find any example for that case in the API.

Is there an easy way to traverse repeatedly over the same collection of entities using an Iterator or something similar?

Example:

```
val player = Iterator(player1, player2, ...)
def doSomething(player: Iterator, condition: Boolean, something: Something): Something = {
    if (condition) something
    else {
        val nextPlayer = it.next()
        val nextCondition = someFunction()
        val somethingNew = someFunction2()
        doSomething(nextPlayer, nextCondition, somethingNew)
    }
}
```

And I want to repeatedly iterate over the players until the condition changes.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over it forever or until a condition is met?

Comment: I want to iterate until a condition is met, I'll put an example of what i would like to have.

Comment: Does my answer satisfy what you need? I can change it to look like yours if not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I haven't looked at Streams yet. I will need to find out if this works with my use case!

Comment: Gah! I made a typo. Originally answered with a Stream but changed my answer when I realised it didn't work in the context of my answer. Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of iterator:

```
object Demo {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val it = Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")

  while (it.hasNext){
     println(it.next())
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: This iterates over the Iterator yes, but how do I repeatedly iterate over the same Iterator? So it should repeat:
 "a", "number", "of", "words", "a", "number", "of", "words", "a", "number", "of", "words", ...

Answer (score 0):

```
  def cycle[T](items: Seq[T])
              (cond:  T => Boolean)
              (doSmt: T => Unit): Unit = 
  {
      def lst: LazyList[T] = LazyList(items: _*)  #::: lst
      lst.takeWhile(cond).foreach(doSmt)
  }

  val players = Seq("one", "two", "three")
  var cnt = 0
  cycle(players) { _ => cnt < 10 }  { t => println(t); cnt += 1 }
```

This version is with LazyList, and relative 'def lst',because of avoiding to use deprecated Streams.

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on using an Iterator, once the Iterator has reached its end you need to instantiate a new iterator or reestablish your iterator:

```
var it = Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")

while(true) {
  if(it.hasNext) println(it.next())
  else it = Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")
}
```

You could otherwise loop through a list infinitely with something like a `while(true)` loop:

```
val seq = Seq("a", "number", "of", "words")
while(true) {
  seq.foreach(println)
}
```

Inside the `foreach` you can do whatever you want with the players.

If you want to end the game after a certain condition is met, you can make a Boolean called something like `gameOver` and wrap this `foreach` in a while loop:

```
val seq = Seq("a", "number", "of", "words")
var gameOver = false

def takeTurn(player: String) = {
  // game logic

  // if player wins
  if(???) gameOver = true
}

while(!gameOver) {
  seq.foreach {
    player => takeTurn(player)
  }
}
```

...or something like that.

Comment: Note: examples are built off Dina Bogdan's answer.